# I need a dress c0de

Tags: python

I'm dealing with classes in python and I'm trying to create a dress code for a Dev by calling a function **init_vibe_check**.
The output is showing me an error that *init_vibe_check is not defined*, and it is right there before the function **create_dress_code_for**. Please help!

Raw Code:

```
#
#  15:03 : October 8, 2021
#  By: Your friendly neighborhood SWE ==> ADMINIXTRATOR
#  AIM: Keep world peace by creating a dress code
#

class Dev:
    level = 'Pre-Senior';

    def __init__(self, name, has_vibe):
        self.name = name;   
        self.has_vibe = has_vibe;

class PeaceKeeper:

    def __init__(self, dev):
        super().__init__();
        self.dev = dev;

    def init_vibe_check(self):
        if self.has_vibe == True:
            return True;
        else: return False;

    def create_dress_code_for(self):
        he_will_receive_props = init_vibe_check(self);

        if he_will_receive_props == True:
            print("Hi " + self.name + ", you are entitled to a dress code");
        else: 
            print(self.name + ", you cannot get a dress code");


# Create two sample Devs
david_chuka = Dev("David Chuka", True);
haks = Dev("Haksoat", False);

# Keep world peace
PeaceKeeper.create_dress_code_for(david_chuka);
PeaceKeeper.create_dress_code_for(haks);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use `self.init_vibe_check()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for calling class methods is not super intuitive. You should be doing this:

```py
he_will_receive_props = self.init_vibe_check()
```

Instead of this:

```py
he_will_receive_props = init_vibe_check(self);
```

(Also note that semicolons are unnecessary in python, they are ignored by the interpreter for the benefit of programmers used to using them)

Comment: Thanks! I got an error at first (AttributeError: 'Dev' object has no attribute 'init_vibe_check'), then I moved the function into class Dev. 
Hurray! Our developers now have a dress code.